# Laravel join post table either with user or Admin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on blog where users as well as admins can create post. So I created 3 tables respectively `users`, `admins` and `posts` table. On post table, there are 2 columns `user_id` and `is_admin`. `user_id` column is id of user or admin. In `is_admin` is Boolean column where post is created by 0 for user and 1 for admins.

The table structure is as follows:

**Users**

```
 -id
 -name
 -email
 -password
 -timestamp
```

**Admins**

```
 -id
 -name
 -email
 -password
 -timestamp
```

**Posts**

```
 -id
 -title
 -image
 -body
 -user_id
 -is_admin
 -timestamp
```

Now I am stuck at displaying name of post user. I have no idea how I join post table with users or admin. Is there any method that I can get user name of either user or admin name like this code?

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->select('posts.*', 'users.id', 'users.name', 'admins.id', 'admins.name')
    ->leftJoin('admins', function ($join) {
        $join->on('admins.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
             ->where('posts.is_admin', '=', 1);
    })
    ->leftJoin('usesrs', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
             ->where('posts.is_admin', '=', 0);
    })
    ->get();
```

I know that I can do it by admins and users with one table and with roles and permissions, but I don't want to change table structure as it will consume more time works already done.

Is there any way that I can get user name of posts either is it Admin or User?

Comment: Could you show us the structure of the three tables. Thanks.

Comment: `users => id, name, email, password, timestamp admins => id, name, email, password, timestamp
posts => id, title, image, body, user_id, is_admin, timestamp`

Comment: I think you can give alias name to your fields eg: user.id as post_user_id, admins.name as post_admin_name. and after that you can check if post_user_id is 0 then show admin's name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is good option or not, but currently I am doing this.

```
    $userPosts = Post::select('posts.*', 'users.name as user_name')
        ->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('user_type', '=', '0')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

    $adminPosts = Post::select('posts.*', 'admins.name as user_name')
        ->join('admins', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'admins.id')
        ->where('user_type', '=', '1')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

    $posts = collect(array_merge($userPosts, $adminPosts))->sortBy('id')->toArray();
```

If you have answer other than this, you are always welcome.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database structure to avoid repeating data. Over time, you will start to performance issues with your database.

For your case, I think you could just assimilate the `Admins` table into the `Users` table. You could move the `is_admin` column from the `Posts` to the combined `Users` table so that you still have a flag for the admin users or better yet, have a `Roles` table wherein you can defined the roles of your users. Like this:

**Users** table:

```
 -id
 -name
 -email
 -password
 -role_id
 -timestamp
```

**Roles** table:

```
 -id
 -name
```

**Posts** table:

```
 -id
 -title
 -image
 -body
 -user_id
 -timestamp
```

With this database structure, you could easily compose your query without overcomplicating it. It doesn't take that much to do this and this is actually a very good practice.

```
$authors = Post::select('posts.*' ,'users.name as user_name')
               ->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
               ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
               ->get()
               ->toArray();
```